# Adding CSS to iframe with no body

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, fonts

I have an iframe tag, where I wish to change the font-family. But the iframe I am linking to does not have a body, it's just text and pictures. So most javascript ways of accessing it don't work. Is there any way around it?

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain as its parent?

Comment: @Prisoner no it is not

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe (and many others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the iFrame is not on the same URL / server, the best way for you do this is with PHP instead.

```
<div class="iframe">
    <?php echo get_file_contents("http://www.google.com"); ?>
</div>
<style>
    .iframe {
        !! Whatever Styles !!
    }
</style>
```

Obviously replacing `!! Whatever Styles !!` with the changes you wish to make to the font. I hope this helped - I'm quite new to Stack Overflow, so if I'm doing anything wrong please tell me :)

Answer (score 2):

If the iframe isn't on the same domain as its parent, there's nothing you can do to modify its contents, because of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: No problem, just thought the OP might want to read more about it :)